# Eliminate Rider (Intellij) ".idea.project-folder.dir" level

Tags: intellij-idea, rider

Rider is creating an extra layer of folders under `.idea`, i.e.:

```
.idea
  - .idea.my-project-folder.dir
    - .idea
      - .gitignore
      - cssdialects.xml
      ... etc
```

This makes it difficult to share settings since not everyone will have the project cloned to the same folder name. Is anyone aware of how to eliminate this extra nested set of folders?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible yet. As far as I can see, you've created an issue in our bug tracker about this: [Eliminate Rider ".idea.project-folder.dir" level](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-92897/Eliminate-Rider-.idea.project-folder.dir-level). Please keep an eye on it to be aware of status changes.